# Passing UI Entities between User Controls in MVP

Tags: c#

I am implementing the MVP pattern for the first time. My Application is a wizard. There is one single form and there are more than one User controls that are embedded into it. 
Each control is a view and each view has a presenter. I am trying to implement the Passive MVP pattern. The presenter is responsible for handling all the actions and updating the view.

The issue is passing the UI Entities. I want to pass the User Input from my first view to the second view as the second view needs to process on it.

All the Views are instantiated on the Win Form.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class which holds all the entities you need.
when opening a new window you pass the class in the constructor and voila, your data has been transferred.

Comment: I have implemented the same. In this case I am creating an object and passing it to the parametrized constructor of the view. 
But as my Main Form carries out all the navigation, 
I am landing up in too many passes. 
The first view talks to the Main Form about the 
user input and the Main Form then talks to the 
second view about the same. 
If tommorrow I feel like adding another layer,
 say a Manager then it increases the headache. 
The first view will tell the manager, 
the manager talks to the Main Form and then the 
Main Form talks to the second view

Comment: Is there any other standard way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

i was thinking about the following scenario:
create an enumerable for holding the different views

```
public enum Views{
First,Second, Manager,Third,
}
```

Create an enumerable for your buttonstate

```
public enum ButtonState{Start,Next,Cancel,Back,}
```

create the class which will hold all the data

```
public class MyData
{
  //properties here
  //Also have a default constructor
  public MyData()
  {
  }
}
```

Then in your form use this new items:

```
Public Views MyViewState { get; set;}
Public ButtonState MyButtonState { get; set;}
Public MyData dataclass { get; set;}

Public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
MyViewState = Views.First;
MyButtonState = ButtonState.Start;
dataclass = new MyData(); //mostly at startup your class data is empty ...
ControlViews();
}

Public void ControlViews()
{
    //Based on your Buttons you will do what each form is asked to do:
      switch(MyButtonState)
      {
       case ButtonState.Start:
        //Since this is your startup: you only need to show your next view and replace you MyViewState
        MyViewState = Views.First;
        ///code for showing your view
       Break;
       case ButtonState.Next:
        //Since this time you probably filled in data you need to know in which MyViewState you are
         Switch (MyViewState)
         {
          Case Views.First:
           //You want to keep your data
           ///Code for placing data into your dataclass
           //After replacing the code, you then need to do some calculations and open the next view
           ///Code for calculations and placing this data in the form
           ///Code for opening the second view
           MyViewState = Views.Second;
          Break;
           // you then need to do this for each MyViewState
         }
       Break;
      }
}
```

The advantage of using this kind of a system is that all your data remains in the class and you simply show/close your views.

That's a way of how i would counter this.